# insert values with select

Tags: sql, syntax, select, insert

I have two tables

```
create table p
(
  x number,
  y number,
  z number
);


create table q 
(
  a number,
  b number,
  c number,
  d  varchar2(20)
);
```

I have inserted

```
insert into p values('1','2','3');
```

now i need to insert into  q  selecting values from  p  with last field getting name like Table _name in table q

values such that table q contains

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3   table_name
```

plz help as soon as possible

Comment: You say that q contains "a b c d 1 2 3 table_name", but you mention only 4 fields in q. I don't understand that. Also, is "table_name" retrieved from somewhere or is it "hard-coded"?

Answer (score 2):

INSERT INTO q(a, b, c, d) SELECT x, y, z, 'table_name' FROM p

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TestTable

DROP TABLE TestTable
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/